# How to get load average in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, performance, performance-monitoring

In linux by "uptime" command you can get the load average in last 15 minutes. But how to get that in windows?

Many had suggested alternative found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/05/12/two-minute-drill-typeperf/). But it is about CPU utilization where load average given by linux give a hint how much processes were waiting for the CPU time.
I saw this question was asked frequently but their date is very old and they did not provide the perfect answer as well.

Also I need to get these from command line not from GUIs.

Comment: Perfmon should give you all you need

Comment: I need to get it from command line

Comment: Use the Get-Counter command in PowerShell then.

Comment: Using that we can get the CPU utilization but not the load average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Load Average" is not natively supported in Windows-based servers. Check this thread - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e5fd5657-726a-4cf0-8d6f-d760bf26ec77/windows-equivalent-to-to-linux-load-average-15-minutes?forum=winserverpowershell

Use PowerShell `Get-Counter` or WMI - `Processor Queue Length` in System `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System`.